# nodejs and database communication - how?

Tags: database, node.js

I've heard much good about nodejs and writting client-server application with it. But I can't get, for example, when developing IM client-server application, how nodejs server script is supposed to talk to database server to actually store it's data? Or may be I miss something and nodejs server scripts are not supposed to do that? If so, please, push me to correct direction.

I've noticed DBSLayer http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer/wiki, but it looks like it's still in beta.

Comment: node.js is great for Comet/WebSockets communication and most IM (instant messaging) solutions don't require a database. Why are you looking into database communication?

Comment: Because offline messages should be stored somewhere. So do contact list, settings, etc

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to grab a module that handles the communication to the database you want. [See here](http://wiki.github.com/joyent/node/modules#database) for a list of modules for node.js. Popular databases that work well with node.js are [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/).

Comment: Couchdb is an excellent choice for use with node. There are some great modules on github for interfacing with the database

Answer (score 1):

As stagas says, you can use a module that handles communication if you want to use an external database.

If you want an internal (=embedded) database, you can use one written in javascript you can require like any other module such as [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) or [nStore](https://github.com/creationix/nstore). They are easier to use and useful if your webapp doesn't need to handle a lot of concurrent connections (e.g. a tool you make for yourself or a small team), or if you write a desktop app using [Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)