# How nodeJs connect to database and fetch data under the hood?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

Hey guys i'm from php background and i'm trying to learn nodeJs currently but i'm bit confused about fetching data from database .

**Problem 1** : How does **NodeJs** communicate with Database under the hood ?

**Problem 2:** Why do we need to make **REST API** in order to do backend stuff (Fetch data ,delete , add data) ? can't we do it like the way we do it in php -> connect to the database and do our backend stuff (Fetch data ,delete , add data).

Yes i know what **API** is and how it works .

I have read this answers : [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934884/nodejs-and-database-communication-how)  but this does not have what i'm looking for .

sorry if that question looks dumb :)

Any help would be helpful Thanks

Comment: P1: Like php way. P2: You don’t need rest api, you can do it like when you play with php.

Comment: @hoangdv Like php way ? but nodejs is not a server side language than how ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you expect from the first part so I'll try to answer the second one.

You don't need to do a RESTful API if you don't want to with NodeJs. It's just a good way to structure your API and make it as easy to use as possible.

The NodeJs API, which is running on server side, offers end-points to other applications to access your data. It can just be an Interface between your database and other apps like your React/Angular front, or other APIs for exemple.

You can also create a NodeJs app like you would with php doing everything from serving Html to directly communicating with the database.

Comment: my question was how nodejs do it under the hood since it is not server side language ,

Comment: Node is a JavaScript execution environment, not a language, that is used server side not client side. Browsers have their own JavaScript environnement.

Comment: If you want to read more about it there is a good article that is more complete and might answer your question more in depth [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-definitive-node-js-handbook-6912378afc6e/)

Answer (score -1):

Node `.js` runs on the *client* side, in the user's browser.  But the database is on the *server.*

The two sides communicate by means of AJAX, which can be referred-to as a "remote procedure call" mechanism:  the server receives the request, prepares the result, encodes them (usually) as JSON, and sends the results back to the client.

Comment: thanks for answer but nodeJs is not a server side language than how it do it under the hood ?